# Is it possible to support a setScrollY() (ScrollView API 14) like function for older API levels?

Tags: android, api, scroll, scrollview

I have a simple first Android app that I am coding. One of my main activities is a ScrollView that's fairly long. In that I have some buttons that call other ListViews. When the ListViews are finished and the ScrollView is back I want the position on the screen to be the same as what it was when the ListView was first called.

I found the getScrollY() and setScrollY() methods and can implement them to keep the position the way I wish.

However, the setScrollY() is an API 14 and up function, and according to my app statistics I have a lot of users on Gingerbread, which is an older API level.

My Question: Is there a method that I have overlooked or can be pointed towards that allows me to have the same functionality as setScrollY() on the older API levels?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked at `scrollTo(getScrollX(), y)`? It's available in all versions of Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo(int%2C%20int)

If you look at the implementation of `setScrollY()`, you'll see:

```
public void setScrollY(int value) {
    scrollTo(mScrollX, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think that works. I did come across another issue after putting that code in place.

Comment: ...which I will have to look up the answer for myself. (and figure out how the commenting system works on here, haha) Thanks!