# Scroll to latest opened place in Screen

Tags: android, scroll

For example I have a long Text inside a TextView in a View, so this is the scenario:

1. I am inside that screen and I've scrolled till somewhere of that
   text
2. Than went back to previous screen, do some other staff in Application
3. Than get back to that screen

So I want to open me the latest position where I've reached with scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Scroll view, you can use`scrollView.getScrollY() or scrollView.getScrollX()`
 this will give you the X/Y offset.

Comment: that's ok but hot to add that position when opening the view

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485927/is-it-possible-to-support-a-setscrolly-scrollview-api-14-like-function-for-o

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implement your "Screens". If they are `Activities` or `Fragments` just save the scroll state when leaving, for example in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out)`, like so:
`out.putInt(SCROLL_Y, view.getScrollY());`

When recreating the screen check if the `Bundle` passed to `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` exists. then just apply it to the content view like so: `view.setScrollY(savedInstanceState.getInt(SCROLL_Y, 0);` where 0 is the default value and SCROLL_Y a key `String` you can choose freely.